# What can a undergraduate do to get the strongest recommendation letter possible?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter, undergraduate

This is basically a follow up question from Tom Church's answer to this question: [How much does a student's ranking in their cohort matter for PhD applications?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/89692/how-much-does-a-students-ranking-in-their-cohort-matter-for-phd-applications).

What can a undergraduate do say in his 2nd or 3rd year to get the strongest recommendation letter possible?  There are the usual answers like talk to your professors etc, but Tom's answer seem to imply there are skills to be learnt in this case.

Comment: This question is a bit subjective and unclear, at least to me. You can pass one or two courses (preferably graduate courses) and ace them. Then work as teaching assistance under his/her supervision and show your personality qualifications. More importantly, approach him/her for being a research assistant and then do great research.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/47373/20457